# Моя задача сделать так что-бы js выводил из массива в консоль только элементы с четным id без if

Tags: javascript, массивы, вывод

```
    let arr = [];
    
    function randomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }
    
    function createArr(elementsCount) {
        for (let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
            arr.push(randomInt(1, 11));
        }

        return arr;
    }

    console.log(createArr(10));
```

Comment: А тернарный оператор можно использовать вместо if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что подразумевается под id? Я сделал два варианта.
Вот вариант с который возвращает элементы у которых четный индекс.

```
    
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function createArr(elementsCount) {
    let arr = [],
        sortedArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
        arr.push(randomInt(1, 11));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let arrElem = (i % 2 === 0) ? sortedArr.push(arr[i]) : '';
    }

    return sortedArr;
}

console.log(createArr(10));
```

Вот второй вариант который возвращает четные элементы:

```
    
function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function createArr(elementsCount) {
    let arr = [],
        sortedArr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
        arr.push(randomInt(1, 11));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let arrElem = (arr[i] % 2 === 0) ? sortedArr.push(arr[i]) : '';
    }

    return sortedArr;
}

console.log(createArr(10));
```